# How can an address on Etherscan have a balance of 0 ETH when I don't see any outgoing transactions?

Tags: etherscan, balances

[image]

I don't know why balance of the address is 0.

Answer (score 3):

It's a smart contract. Smart contracts can only send ETH by using 'internal transactions'. On Etherscan, they don't appear on the 'Transactions' tab. You can see them on the 'Internal Txns' tab.